# Loop through html cells and perform a function if conditionals are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var tableBody = document.getElementById("firstTableBody"),
  secondTable = document.getElementById("secondTable");

function insertRow() {
  var Row = tableBody.insertRow();
  for (var c = 0; c < 3; c += 1) {
    Row.insertCell(c);
  }
  var Fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Strawberries"],
    random_Fruits = Fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * Fruits.length)];
  Row.cells[0].innerHTML = random_Fruits;
  Row.cells[1].innerHTML = 100;
  var Sellbtn = document.createElement('button');
  Sellbtn.innerHTML = "Sell"
  Sellbtn.onclick = function Sell() {
    if (secondTable.rows.length < 1) {
      var Row = secondTable.insertRow();
      for (var f = 0; f < 2; f += 1) {
        Row.insertCell(f);
      }
      Row.cells[0].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
      Row.cells[1].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < secondTable.rows.length; i += 1) {
        if (secondTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML) {
          secondTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = +this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
        } else {
          var Rowz = secondTable.insertRow();
          for (var k = 0; k < 4; k += 1) {
            Rowz.insertCell(k);
          }

          Rowz.cells[0].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
          Rowz.cells[1].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
        }
      }
    }


  }
  Row.cells[2].appendChild(Sellbtn);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Sold</th>
      <th>
        <button onclick="insertRow()">Insert</button>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="firstTableBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Sold</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="secondTable">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

I insert a row with randomly inserted fruit name and a dynamically added button called sell. When I click on sell it should check if the fruit name of that row exists in the second table or not if so then it should add the sold amount in the row that's in the second table that has the same name. If not then simply add a new row in the second table with the name and sold amount. jQuery is ok.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with jQuery? You don't appear to be using it.

Comment: cause hes open to using jquery. OP: "jQuery is ok."

Comment: Hm, how'd I miss that? -.-

Comment: Not clear from snippet demo what the problem is. Please clarify what part of code is causing issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possible solution, replacement for your function Sell()

```
Sellbtn.onclick = function Sell() {

var found = false,
    rows = secondTable.rows,
    numrows = rows.length,
    tofind = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML,
    foundin,
    numToAdd = parseInt(this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML),
    num,
    x;

    for(x=0;x<numrows;x++){

        if(rows[x].cells[0].innerHTML === tofind){

            found = true;

            foundin = x;

        }

    }

    if(found){

        num = parseInt(rows[foundin].cells[1].innerHTML) + numToAdd;

        rows[foundin].cells[1].innerHTML = num;

    }
    else{

        var Row = secondTable.insertRow();
        for (var f = 0; f < 2; f += 1) {
            Row.insertCell(f);
        }
        Row.cells[0].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML;
        Row.cells[1].innerHTML = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.insert').on('click', function() {
        var Fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Strawberries"];
        var random_Fruit = Fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * Fruits.length)];
        var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
        clone.css('display', '');
        clone.closest('tr').find('.item').html(random_Fruit);
        clone.appendTo('#firstTableBody');        
    });
    $('#firstTableBody').on('click', '.sell', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = $(this).closest('tr').find('.item').html();
        var add = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.number').html());
        
        var inTable2 = [];
        $('#secondTable tr').each(function() {
            var fruit = $(this).find('.item').html();
            inTable2.push(fruit);
        });
        console.log(inTable2);
        
        if ($.inArray(item, inTable2) > -1) {
            console.log('in array');
            $('#secondTable tr').each(function() {
                var fruitIn2 = $(this).find('.item').html();
                if (fruitIn2 == item) {
                    var sold = parseInt($(this).find('.number').html());
                    $(this).find('.number').html(sold + add);
                }
            });
        }        
        else {
            console.log('add');
            var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id', '');
            clone.css('display', '');
            clone.closest('tr').find('.item').html(item);
            clone.closest('tr').find('.sellTd').remove();
            clone.appendTo('#secondTable');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>
            <button class="insert">Insert</button>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="firstTableBody">
        <tr id="template" class="fruit" style="display:none;">
            <td class="item"></td>
            <td class="number">100</td>
            <td class="sellTd"><button class="sell">Sell</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/><br/>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="secondTable">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

sorry i kinda used all jquery cause it makes it simpler for me to code in and think xp but it works :D